# Starting Android application from browser URI

Tags: android, html, android-browser

```
  <activity
                android:name=".RegisterationCompletion"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter  >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:scheme="test" />
                 </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

I need to start android application from browser URI but this code is not working in Ginger Bread and other higher version. Any idea?

Comment: Is it working in lower Versions?

Comment: test://192.168.254.84:8080/testregisteration/  i am giving link like this and it is hosted locally..

Comment: Your code seems fine, though creating custom schemes is not recommended. However, if you are just typing this URL into the browser, that will not work. A link on a Web page should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="Testapp" />
     </intent-filter>
```

**Important Point:we have to access the link using href**

Careful with UPPERCASE and LOWERCASE letters in AndroidManifest.xml.

Wherever you see 'Testapp' instead of 'TestApp'.Android cannot handle the uppercase letters except for the first one.

this code works fine for me...